# jQuery delegate issue in Firefox 11

Tags: jquery, firefox

jQuery delegate function is giving 'not a function' error for my plugin. So I tried running the example given on [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), even that is giving an error in Firefox 11. It works fine in safari and chrome.

Any thoughts/comments?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 1.7+, use .on() instead of .delegate()

Comment: I didn't mention, but I switched to using on method, even then I was receiving the same issue. The actual issue was, I have a greasemonkey script which was loading version 1.3.2. Disabling that script solved the issue.