# jquery window.onbeforeunload not working with a href=javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have below code to invalidate session on window unload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        console.log("closing the browser, invalidating the session");
        $.ajax({
            url : "/inValidateOnBrowserClose.html",
            type : "get",
            cache : false,
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(" invalidated session on browser close event");
        });

    }
    return true;
};

$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $("button").click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

});
```

all working fine, but i have a page where i have a dynamically created buttons.

```
<span class="myButton"><a href="javascript:submitForm" >Update </a></span>
```

when i click above anchor (button) my window unload event is getting called (in my case it should not get called), i am surprised why `$("a").click(function())` is not called in first place, i am trying to fix this but no luck. Thanks for your answers

Comment: So, you never added a click event on the dynamically added `a`-tag? Could you show us the code for when you're adding this `a`-tag dynamically?

Comment: have you tried to call with class name or id?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `delegate` here like below for binding click events to dynamically generated elements :

```
$(function() {
    $(document).delegate("a","click",function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $(document).delegate("button","click",function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

});
```

And this works for already existing elements, so no need to write separate click binding.

For firefox user `delegate` function may not work so they can use `on`. please see below code

```
$(function() {
        $("a").on("click",function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        });
        $("button").on("click",function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        });

    });
```

[Stackoverflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914696/jquery-delegate-issue-in-firefox-11)

Comment: this is not working in firefox for static buttons.. after added static methods back it worked fine

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/84/ ... it is working on both chrome and firefox (version 25.0.1). Can you please share you JSFiddle so that I can look over it?

Comment: FYI [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is now preferred in place of [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). 'On' could be used at any place where 'delegate' is used.